# How do I get parent div to exactly contain child div that has position: relative with offset?

Tags: css

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="first">
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
}
.first{
    background-color: rgba(20,20,200,0.5);
    height: 100px;
}
.second{
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,.5);
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W5e4e/

I need the parent class to exactly contain both children.  When the child div is positioned to relative (in order to moved it up or down), the parent class still sees the child in it's static position.  You can see the 20px gap at the bottom. I need the parent to exactly contain the children.  Is there a non-javascript solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an offset, [use a negative margin to move the child instead](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/W5e4e/1):

```
.second{
    margin-top:-20px;
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,.5);
    height: 100px;
}
```